# Using DD Disk Image on Red Hat

Tags: linux, rhel, virtualbox, ddrescue

How can I use `dd` command on a Linux Red Hat Server 5 to obtain a disk image and then use it eventually in Virtual Box?

Comment: Not a duplicate of [Transferring Operating System from VM to Physical System](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102466/transferring-operating-system-from-vm-to-physical-system), but the opposite of it.  Google for `p2v` or `physical to virtual`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this myself but this is how I have understood it to be possible.

Live boot to server and mount big enough external hard drive where you can store image. Image server's hard drive:

```
dd if=/dev/sdX bs=4k conv=noerror,sync of=/mount_point_of_extHDD/serverIMG.dd
```

Then let's zero out unused blocks:

```
file /path/to/serverIMG.dd
```

Check startsector value in file command output, multiply it by 512. There is your "offset" value. Mount image:

```
mount -o loop,rw,offset=<counted_value_here> -t <partitions_filesystem_type> /path/to/serverIMG.dd /mnt/tmp
cat /dev/zero > zeroes.file
rm zeroes.file
```

Then unmount the image. Boot into machine where you have virtualbox installed so you can modify raw image to vhd:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw serverIMG.dd serverIMG.vhd --format VHD
```

Answer (score 0):

## VirtualBox - convert RAW image to VDI

dd if=/dev/sdb of=./sdb.raw

To use it with VirtualBox we need to convert it to the VDI format:

$ VBoxManage convertdd sdb.raw sdb.vdi --format VDI

OR

$ VBoxManage convertdd sdb.raw sdb.vmdk --format VMDK