# distribute a linux environment to students

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a Linux VM in virtualBox, with a some programmes installed (R, Rstudio...etc). I would like to distribute this same machine with all programmes installed to students, they can then start with this basic environment and then add their own programs.
What the efficient way to do this, 
Thanks!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102466/transferring-operating-system-from-vm-to-physical-system

Comment: You can clone your image in virtualbox.

Comment: Can refer any tutorial? I'm very newbie.

Answer (score 2):

I do this for my students as well...

Just simply export the VM and put the resulting OVA file online someplace and provide a link.

You'll want to have docs on installing VirtualBox or perhaps Portable VirtualBox, a doc on importing the VM, etc.

Note:  To avoid TONS of questions about how to log in, usernames and passwords should be simple and generic - I use "student" and "learnjava" for my Java class VM, "student" and "learnsql" for the one I use for my SQL class, etc.  Whether for login to the deskop (I use Mint 18.x) or a mysql/mariadb user, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As previously suggested, exporting the VM as an *.OVA file and sharing it would be a good way to go.  You could also have your students use Vagrant Scotch Box as it's a pretty short list of commands to get a VM running. 
  https://box.scotch.io/